Excel INDEX function gives back just one column if I wirte {1,2} array in the optional column pos)
Table1



Column A
Column B




1
A


2
B


3
C



this is my function:
=INDEX(Table1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),{1,2})

and the result is:
I expect to get back the whole table...
Could you please help me?
I use Microsoft office professional plus 2021
I tried everything what I could...


Try using {1\2} as your array constant (you could also use the SEQUENCE() function for your columns as well as your rows).

{1\2}  WORKS!!! omg SEQUENCE() also works!!
thanks a lot guys!!!!!
